# How to upload images onto Google Glass device and view them?

Tags: images, google-glass

The first part of the question: I've got a Google Glass device and I plugged it into the USB port. The drivers install fine on my WinXP. I do see the Glass directory pop up in My Computer. I'm able to take a picture, as well as copy it to my PC. However, how do I copy or upload a picture to the device? It does not allow Paste. Right-click -> Paste option is disabled. Dragging a file also doesn't work.

I've looked at the following links, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209684/google-glass-upload-files-using-http-client) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153327/google-glass-image-upload-issue), but that's not what I want.

The second part of the question is how to view all images on the Glass device, with something like VLC APK?

**Update:** A workaround that I've found is to share images/videos from another Google+ account to your Glass device Google+ account. This seems to be the easiest way so far that I've encountered.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Glass, which is not an Android device. Although it's based on 4.0.3, it's not in any useful way, because you can't run unmodified Android apps on it: there's no overlap between Glass expertise and expertise on Android phones/tablets. That said, there hasn't been a discussion on meta, about Glass and whether it has a place on this site: so it's up to all the users to decide.

Comment: I have started a discussion on our meta site on whether or not Google Glass is on-topic here: [Is Google Glass within this site's scope?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1667)

Comment: From the [discussion on meta](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1667/is-google-glass-within-this-sites-scope), the consensus seems to be that we should include Google Glass in the site's remit, so I've voted to reopen the question.

Comment: I've cleaned up some outdated comments here.

Answer (score 0):

Your best be to view images on Google Glass would be to use the 'mirror-api' methods to create an application that you can run on Google Glass.